# Quiz algorithm question

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm writing a a multiple-choice quiz program for Android, and would like to add a randomization feature to it, that is, the questions will come from a list, and the order will differ each time a quiz is taken. I have a list of about 600 questions which are sequentially numbered and stored in a hash map.  The limitation is that I don't want to ask the same question twice during a given quiz.

I was initially thinking about creating a separate map to track the questions asked. Then, to get the next question, have a loop which gets a random number (based on the range of questions the user has specified to select from),  and check the answered map to see if that question has already been asked. However, as the number of questions answered increases, this would require a linearly increasing amount of lookups for each question asked, until 100 lookups is reached.

If I limit the number of questions on a given quiz to 100, then 100 lookups might not take a long time. I could put a small delay factor in to keep the user for noticing.

Another possible solution is to create a map containing an the unasked questions at the start of the quiz. When a question is answered, delete it from the unasked question map. To select the next question, convert the unanswered question map to an array, get the array size, and get a random number between zero and the array size.  Use that entry from the unanswered question array.

This second solution appeals due to its simplicity, but the array extraction process could get slow with a large number of questions to select from (it could eventually number in the thousands).

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: I deleted my answer because FrustratedWithFormsDesigner said what I was thinking of while I was writing (and said it better), but I'm still curious: If you have a sequentially numbered list of items, why are you storing them in a map instead of a list? Also, it would be faster to use an array of `boolean`s to represent whether a question has been answered than to check against the map every time, but the answers present even better methods.

Comment: The map may not be necessary. In this case I went with it because the number is coming from an xml list, and I know for sure that what I see in the list will match the entry on the map, which may not be the case if I use the array numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an array with the integers from 1 to 600, shuffle it and take the first N elements for your questions. That will give you a random chain of numbers without repetitions.

Comment: I like all the answers, but this will be the simplest to implement.

Comment: @Jack BeNimble: Can a user take the quiz more than once? How do you ensure that the second quiz does not contain questions from the first one?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner If needed, one way is to take the first N numbers from the array, then the next N, and so on. When the array is "exhausted", a new shuffled array is generated and the process is repeated. Something like that.

Comment: @Frustrated - very good point. However, I would actually prefer that the app repeat questions the user is having trouble with. I haven't worked out that part yet.

Answer (score 6):

This might help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

It is an algorithm to shuffle the items in a list. The question I have is: will one quiz consist of all 600 questions, or does the user get asked a random subset of the questions and if so, is it possible for them to get asked different questions from the 600 again later? You could always create and save a user-specific shuffled ordering for each user so that they can resume their shuffled quiz later...

Comment: +1, good suggestion. Make an array of questions, shuffle them, then loop through them.

Comment: Ah, you remembered the name Fisher–Yates faster than I did. +1

Comment: That is a fiendishly clever algorithm.

Comment: @Jack BeNimble: I wish I could take credit for it ;) And you'll probably have to implement it anyway, even for the accepted answer ;)

Comment: @Frustrated: I'm hoping that Java's "shuffle" will work out on this one. However, if not it looks easy enough to implement the Fisher-Yates algorithm.

Comment: @Jack BeNimble: I'm not sure what's inside Java's "Shuffle" (I didn't even know there was one) but it might be an implementation of Fisher-Yaites...

Answer (score 2):

I prefer generate random permutation (stored in int[n] array numbers from 0 to n - 1) and take consequently numbers from this list.

But actually question is what's easier for you to implement. There is no difference for 600 items.